# I can't watch a video after grabbing the video URI and uploading them to back4app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to be able to watch the video after I upload it to my server. Right now, I grab the URI from the library and parse it and upload it. But then when I download it from my server, it is unplayable. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and suggest some code? Here is my current code...

```
async getVideo() {


const videoOptions: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
}

  await this.camera.getPicture(videoOptions).then(async (imageData) => {
    this.data = {
      base64: base64Image
    };

this.parseFile = await new Parse.File('video.mp4', this.data);
await this.photosOnline.get("lAIBjItZ4Y").then(async (player) => {
   await player.set("video1", this.parseFile)
    await player.save();

}, (error) => {
  // The object was not retrieved successfully.
console.log("error is " + error);
this.presentAlert();
});
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    // Handle error
  });

}
```

so, it sends it to my server (it sends something) but it is unplayable when I download it. When I test it on the phone, it pulls up all my videos and lets me select one and then it sends some info to my server.

Comment: Share your Upload code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Here is the information that gets uploaded --> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20210221_180739.mp4             I'm seeing that it is really wrong.... I thought it was a base64 string lol

Comment: Any suggestions how to take that and make it into what I want? I'm not even sure what I should make it into actually... Can I change the DestiniationType to something to fix it? Is FILE_URI what i want?

Comment: change this from `this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` to `this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` and it will give you base64.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I thought I was saved! It is really weird though.... the output is still /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20210221_180739.mp4...... could the plugin be broken? :(

Comment: Update your question with your Current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much experimentation, I'm pretty certain that the plugin just doesn't not allow you to get the base64 of videos. The photos are able to get the base64, but no matter what the settings are set to, if you are selecting a video, it will always give you the URI.